# get data using link (URL varriable) then save to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to click on a link '1' for 'LIKE' and same way '0' for 'DISLIKE'  will be save to db without refresh page

Comment: Please ask a specific technical question. What you are asking at the moment is much too broad.

Comment: -1 , sorry but thats just lazy

Comment: send data [ using url variable ] without refresh/redirect page

Comment: @shaji if you ask a more detailed question, I'm sure there will be no downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with ajax function

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to research [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

JQuery has a number of plugins to AJAX-ify forms, or you can use the raw JQuery [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to send data back to a PHP script.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp), and here's [another](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html).

Answer (score 0):

look into AJAX, you could use jQuery's post function also.